# how to query to get the last inserted data as first item in the list android

Tags: android, sqlite

Iam retrieving data from the database and displaying it as a list,
in the list i want to display the last inserted one as the first and soon
How to acheive this?

Iam fetching data using the following query

```
public Cursor fetchdata() {
        DBHelper.onOpen(db);
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_Table, new String[] { "Message",
                , "UserInfo",  "timeStamp" }, null,
                null, null, null, null);

        return mCursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the method of Cursor class **mCursor.moveToLast();**

Comment: thanx when retrieving the data we have to mCursor.movetoLast()till mCursor.movetoPrevious()

Answer (score 0):

i think you have use this way may help full

```
 Cursor c=dbAdapter.fetchdata();
 int MSG=.getColumnIndex("Message");
 for(c.moveToLast();!c.isBeforeFirst();c.moveToPrevious())
           {

    }
```